# Cc Sender on PHP Mail() Form

Tags: php, phpmailer

having troubles getting a copy of my web form sent back to the sender.

```
$recipient = "myemail@myserver.com";
$subject = "Contact Form"; 
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
$mailheader .= "Cc: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader)
```

Comment: Try removing `\r\n` [from the end](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#example-3909) of `$mailheader`.

Comment: Comes through normally but no email sent to the Cc :/

Answer (score 0):

Don't use \n\r, just put the email.
Don't use $mailheader. Use instead:

```
    $mail->From      = "a@domain.com";
    $mail->FromName  = "name of a";
    $mail->Subject   = "subject mail";
    $mail->Body      = "body mail";
    $mail->AddReplyTo("name1", "name1@something.com");
    $mail->AddAddress("name2", "name2@something.com");
    $mail->AddCC("name3", "name3@something.com");
    $mail->AddBCC("name4", "name4@something.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "From: ".$agent." <".$email.">\n";
$headers .= "cc: ".$email."\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: Name <info@domain.com>\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
$headers .= "X-Priority: 1\n";
$headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: High\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: My mailer";
```

This gave me correct headers which seemed to be the fowl of why it wouldn't CC, now in gmail it shows correct CC but what I seem to be fight is outlook or hotmail addresses blocking it as I was using a @hotmail for the CC email.